I'm using Next.js parallel routes and I noticed a bug while making some changes in it
Inside the modal (children) there is an id being rendered and I just added a form with a button whose action is a server action callback function that just redirects to the '/' page , after that when I click on another parallel route, it doesn't render and just changes the url. How can I fix this?
Video of the issue:
https://utfs.io/f/25e347be-3431-4836-a0db-ce95c9f0ca2b-dj5nsp.mkv
Code:
# This is the page.tsx inside (.)photos\[id]

import { redirect } from 'next/navigation';
import { Modal } from './modal';

export default function PhotoModal({
params: { id: photoId },
}: {
   params: { id: string };
}) {
return 
  <Modal>
   <div>{photoId}</div>
   <form action={async ()=>{
     "use server";
     redirect('/');
    }}>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>        
   </form>    
  </Modal>;
}

Steps to recreate
https://github.com/vercel/nextgram
Just use Nextgram's repo and change the page.tsx above
I was expecting it to open another modal after being redirected but it just changes the url
